# How to change status of child workflow of change order in CA SDM?

Tags: java, xml

Recently I have been working in CA SDM. on Broadcom documentation is available and community provides answers but it is for them who have purchased it. So, I am asking on stack overflow for my solution.

I have created a change order in existing setup of CA SDM. With category I have analyzed that workflows have been generated. But now I want to change the status of first workflow task. It is popular to use CA SDM's own rest apis to perform operations so that it works automatically in business logic. If I do it with Hibernate it will be conflict.

I tried with service "https://hostname:port/caisd-rest/chg/599280" and HTTPPUT in java. It is given in sample code to change description in chg table and with my sample code it is changing too.

Now, wf object is workflow and representing workflow tasks table. There are 19 wf creatred as per category when change order was created. It is automatic in the system. But now, task is changing the first of 19 wfs status to Done from Pending.

I tried with below xml in java program,

```
 <chg>
      <description>Updated status via xml</description>
      <children> // or <workflow> 
           <wf COMMON_NAME="Attmnt" REL_ATTR="DONE" id="1190224">
           </wf>
      </children> // or </workflow>
 </chg>
```

Please provide help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not supporting collection because if you change one the next one will automatically update its own status to Pending or skip.

URL can be `https://hostname:port/caisd-rest/wf/1190224`

XML should be as below:

```
 <wf id="1190224">
    <status id="40001">DONE</status>
 </wf>
```

Do not forget to use PUT method instead of POST or GET.